# QR Code decoder library for python

Tags: python, qr-code, zbar-sdk

I am trying to build an application in python that would encode and decode QR codes. I am successful with  the encoder, but i don't find libraries(but [zbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar)) for decoding in python. I am using Python 2.7 in a Windows 7 system.

I am not able to install [zbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar) in my system. I installed the dependency module required by the library and even then I end up with so many errors, whenever I try to install it - so many syntax errors in zbar.h and in zbarmodule.c. I don't understand why and clueless about what the problem is.

I get the following errors while installing zbar

```
C:\Users\vijay>easy_install zbar
Searching for zbar
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/zbar/
Reading http://zbar.sourceforge.net
Best match: zbar 0.10
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zbar/zbar-0.10.zip#md5=9e99
ef2f6b471131120982a0dcacd64b
Processing zbar-0.10.zip
Running zbar-0.10\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\vijay\appdata\local\
temp\easy_install-hv_kag\zbar-0.10\egg-dist-tmp-sxhz3s
zbarmodule.c
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(685) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(687) : error C2085: 'zbar_processor_parse_config' : n
ot in formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(687) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(761) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(763) : error C2085: 'zbar_processor_error_spew' : not
in formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(763) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(768) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before
'const'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(777) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(778) : error C2085: 'zbar_processor_get_error_code' :
not in formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(778) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(882) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(884) : error C2085: 'zbar_video_error_spew' : not in
formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(884) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(889) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before
'const'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(897) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(898) : error C2085: 'zbar_video_get_error_code' : not
in formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(898) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(968) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(970) : error C2085: 'zbar_window_error_spew' : not in
formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(970) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(975) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before
'const'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(984) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(985) : error C2085: 'zbar_window_get_error_code' : no
t in formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(985) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before
'{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1050) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1052) : error C2085: 'zbar_image_scanner_parse_config
' : not in formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1052) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' befor
e '{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1141) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1143) : error C2085: 'zbar_decoder_parse_config' : no
t in formal parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1143) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' befor
e '{'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1276) : error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'inline'
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1278) : error C2085: 'zbar_scan_rgb24' : not in forma
l parameter list
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(1278) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' befor
e '{'
zbarmodule.c(65) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
zbarmodule.c(66) : error C2065: 'major' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(66) : error C2065: 'minor' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(68) : error C2065: 'major' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(68) : error C2065: 'minor' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(133) : error C2275: 'zbar_error_t' : illegal use of this type as an
expression
C:\Python27\include\zbar.h(121) : see declaration of 'zbar_error_t'
zbarmodule.c(133) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'e
i'
zbarmodule.c(133) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(134) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(134) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(134) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(135) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(135) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(136) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(146) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an exp
ression
    c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
zbarmodule.c(146) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(147) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(151) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(151) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(151) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(152) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(152) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(152) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(153) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(153) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(153) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(154) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(154) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(154) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(155) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(155) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(155) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(156) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(156) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(156) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(157) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(157) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(157) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(158) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(158) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(158) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(159) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(159) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(159) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(160) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(160) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(160) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(162) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(162) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(162) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(163) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(164) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(164) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(164) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_AddObject' : different types for fo
rmal and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(164) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(164) : error C2065: 'ei' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(167) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an exp
ression
    c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
zbarmodule.c(167) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(167) : error C2065: 'mod' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(167) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(167) : warning C4024: 'PyModule_GetDict' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(169) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(169) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(169) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(171) : error C2065: 'dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(171) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(171) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(183) : error C2275: 'PyObject' : illegal use of this type as an exp
ression
        c:\python27\include\object.h(108) : see declaration of 'PyObject'
zbarmodule.c(183) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(185) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(185) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(185) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(186) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(186) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(186) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(187) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(187) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(187) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(188) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(188) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(188) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(189) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(189) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(189) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(190) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(190) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(190) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(191) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(191) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(191) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(192) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(192) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(192) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(193) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(193) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(193) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(194) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(194) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(194) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(195) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(195) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(195) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(196) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(196) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(196) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
zbarmodule.c(197) : error C2065: 'tp_dict' : undeclared identifier
zbarmodule.c(197) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'PyObject *' differs in levels o
f indirection from 'int'
zbarmodule.c(197) : warning C4024: 'zbarEnumItem_New' : different types for form
al and actual parameter 1
error: Setup script exited with error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Can anyone help me with zbar installation or get me a library with which I can decode QR codes?

Comment: Please past the error so people can understand what you are doing

Comment: I have included the errors, please look through and tell me what the problem is. Thanks @lafada and wooble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pyqrcode](http://pyqrcode.sourceforge.net/) supports encoding and decoding QR codes.

Regarding zbar, as other have commented , it is difficult to help you without knowing any of the error messages.

Did you install zbar from Windows binary packages or source ?

zbar has a prebuilt Windows binary package available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/zbar/0.10/zbar-0.10-setup.exe/download), it
also has binary for the Python modules for 2.5 and 2.6 available [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar).

Regarding zbar installation via see these [zbar Installation Instructions](http://code.google.com/p/qrdecoder/wiki/zbarInstallation)

A summary of the steps you need to take based on the above link to install the zbar Python module from source is shown below.

1. Install zbar (preferably  from the binary  [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/zbar/0.10/zbar-0.10-setup.exe/download))
2. Install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)
3. Add the Zbar\bin and MinGw\bin (binary installation directories) to your Windows Path Variable
4. Download the Zbar Python module source from [here](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/z/zbar/zbar-0.10.zip#md5=9e99ef2f6b471131120982a0dcacd64b) and unzip it to a temporary folder
5. Modify the setup.py script to use custom zbar include and library path.

   Add `from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_vars` to line 3 and 
   add the following parameters to the Extension call:

   ```
       library_dirs=["""zbarlibdirectory"""],
       include_dirs=[get_config_vars('INCLUDEDIR'),
                     get_config_vars('INCLUDEPY'),
                     """zbarincludedirectory"""]
   ```

   where zbarlibdirectory is something like `C:\zbar\lib` and zbarincludedirectory is something    like `C:\zbar\include`
6. Install zbar Python module using modified setup.py

   `python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32`

   `python setup.py install`

As for installation pyqrcode on Windows7, I haven't done so yet but believe you just for the source instructions under the relevant heading, first installing all the dependencies then running make and make install either using nmake or make from MinGW.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Appleman. How do I install pyqrcode in Windows now? And I have included the errors that I get in zbar, I installed it from the source.(from [zbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar/0.10) package in pypi using easy_install)